# Serving mp3 files using the webpack file loader

Tags: webpack, mp3, webpack-file-loader

I have a problem with getting my mp3 files to work using the webpack file loader.

This is the issue:

I have a mp3 file on my harddisk, that if I open using chrome by for example "c:\somefolder\somemp3file.mp3" opens up in a tab in the browser and plays just fine.

However, when I serve the exact same file using webpack it does not work. I have configured the loader in webpack like this:

```
{
    test: /\.(gif|jpg|png|mp3|aac|ogg)$/,
    loader: 'file'
}
```

Then, when I'm trying to link to the file I require it inside my javascript, like this:

```
require('file!./../content/somemp3file.mp3');
```

this correctly returns me the url for the mp3 file.

If I try to manually go to `localhost:8080` followed by the url returned by require, the mp3 player in Chrome pops up like I expect it to, but the file cannot be played, and it's not possible to click on the play button like the file is corrupted or something.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Try removing the `file!` when you call `require()`.  That actually causes a second `.mp3` file to be generated, probably ~80bytes.  If you look at the file it's just a module export of a string (URL to the actual `.mp3` file that is bundled).  So leave the webpack config as you have it, and in your js file, `var src = require('./../content/somemp3file.mp3'); document.getElementById('myAudio').src = src;`

Answer (score 17):

Use file-loader like this:

```
{
    test: /\.mp3$/,
    loader: 'file-loader'
}
```

Comment: `SRC is not defined`

Answer (score 15):

Start off with webpack 5, [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules) replaces the old `raw-loader`, `url-loader` and `file-loader`.

Add the following rule to your `webpack.config.js` file,

```js
   rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|ogg|mp3|wav)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
   ]
```

In your project `.js` file, create an audio file and play it like this,

```js
import myAudioResource from './path-to-your-audio-file/audio.wav';
const myAudio = new Audio(myAudiolResource);
myAudio.play();
```

You don't have to configure images and audios separately. `asset/resource` can process `(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|ogg|mp3|wav)` all at a time.

You can change the folder of emitted files by setting `output.assetModuleFilename` in your webpack configuration. For example, the following script will emit your images and audio files under the `dist/assets/` folder.

```js
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[hash][ext][query]' // add this line
  },
```

For more information, check the official doc [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer – just a heads-up that there's a typo: `myAudiolResource` should be `myAudioResource`

Answer (score 8):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41158166/11878375 - it's correctly answer, but define SRC like this:

```
var path = require('path');

var SRC = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main/js');
```

For example, I am using [react-chat-ui](https://github.com/brandonmowat/react-chat-ui) with webpack and this is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

const SRC = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');

module.exports = {
  entry: './jsx/App.jsx',
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    path:
        '/java/helios-backend/src/main/resources/static/js'
        // __dirname + '/js/'
    ,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: '#sourcemap',
  stats: {
   colors: true,
   reasons: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              bypassOnDebug: true,
              disable: true, 
            },
          },
        ]},
      {
        test: /\.mp3$/,
        include: SRC,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      }

    ]
  }
};
```

And do not forget to install the [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) before:

```
npm install file-loader --save-dev
```

Answer (score 5):

This is how I process mp3 files using Webpack in Nuxt 2:

```js
  build: {
  
    loaders: {
      vue: {
        transformAssetUrls: {
          audio: 'src',
        },
      },
    },

    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.mp3$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]',
        },
      })
    },
  },
```

Now you can write `<audio src="@/assets/water.mp3"></audio>` in your templates and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

My solution:  install the file-loader. Update webpack.config.js:

```
// webpack.config.js
rules: [
            {
                test: /\.mp3$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[path][name].[ext]'
                }
            }
```

Project.js :

```
const smthn = require('../sound.mp3');
const sound = new Audio('./sound.mp3');
(() => sound.play())();
```

Comment: What is webpack.config.js? I added this file, and nothing changed(

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of the **file-loader**, I solved this by upgrading the **file-loader** from 4.x.x to 6.x.x, then add **mp3** to the normal webpack config plugin settings for files =>

```html
// webpack.config.js

      { 
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|xml|mp3)?$/i,
        use: "file-loader"
      }
      // OR
      {
        test: /\(mp3|wav|mpe?g|ogg)?$/i,
        use: 'file-loader'
      }
      
      // OR BOTH
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// webpack.config.js
{
    test: /\.(mp3|wav)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    query: {
        name: 'media/[name].[ext]'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in an electron application with React :

> ```
> npm install file-loader
> ```

then added this in `webpack.common.js` inside `module` object and inside `rules` array :

> ```
>   {
>     test: /\.(mp3|wav)$/,
>     loader: "file-loader",
>   }
> ```

then simply `import your_sound from "/your_path/your_sound.wav";`

Comment: That's for older version of Webpack. No need additional loader for 5-th version. `asset/resource` type for the same operation out of the box.