# Getting "Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: text/html" Error when using react-player to play mp3 file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-player

I've been trying to play a single audio file with [react-player](https://github.com/CookPete/react-player) but it doesn't seem to be reading the file properly. This is the React prop that I'm using to play my file.

```
<ReactPlayer 
    forceAudio
    controls
    width='100%'
    url='../../../../../build/assets/audio/Big_O_Opening_US_Version.mp3'
    type = 'audio/mp3'
/>
```

Whenever my app renders the player doesn't read the file and gives me the following error in the Firefox console:

```
Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: text/html
```

Other browsers that I've used don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Add a file loader in webpack for mp3

Your loader needs to understand the file you use, you can use the standard file-loader in webpack to bundle these files to your build. There's a question on how to use this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41158166/2504407). Then import the file as a variable and pass it to your component. Import is important because thats how webpack sees what to bundle.

```
import mp3 from '../../../../../build/assets/audio/Big_O_Opening_US_Version.mp3';

...

<ReactPlayer 
    forceAudio
    controls
    width='100%'
    url={mp3}
    type = 'audio/mp3'
/>
```

Comment: Tried this out, but I ended up with this error in node:

`Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../../../build/assets/audio/Big_O_Opening_US_Version.mp3 which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.`

Comment: yeah, correct your path or move your assets folder inside your project